Rtools 4.3 not recognized in system PATH after installation on Windows 10
I installed the Rtools43 installer and executed install on an I-7 Asus Zen book laptop running Windows 10.
I then ran the following commands to configure RTools:
write('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', file = "~/.Renviron", append = TRUE)
Sys.which("make")
Sys.getenv("PATH")
install.packages("pkgbuild")
library(pkgbuild)
find_rtools(debug = TRUE)

I cannot get R to create a makefile directory with
Sys.which("make")
make 
  ""

RTools directory is not recognised even after adding c:\rtools\usr\bin to the PATH environment variable. I hope, I have created a reprex. If there is anything else I need to add, please tell me.
The issue is now solved , the solution was to archive files to make more memory for my system, to run on win 10/11 you need at least 30g free for the memory swap file to hold complex data in memory.

Which R version are you using?

Did you restart R after changing the path? Environment variables are set when a program first launches. What is the output of Sys.getenv("PATH")?

The reason why it was not installing was a true pebcac, there was insufficient memory on the hard drive, I cleared 30 gigs and it installed, thanks for all your suggestions. PS. It does not need 30g, but to run anything intensive on win 10 or 11 you need 30 g drive space free.
